# Replicate "Countif" in PowerBI using DAX

Tags: dax, countif

I am a new user to DAX and Power BI, but I am familiar with Excel. I want to replicate these countif formulas in DAX. In Excel, they are counting how many times a specific text string (in this case, the name of a brand) appears in the column, for example:
=COUNTIF(BH2:BH31,"*Brand_A*"), it is counting how many times the text "Brand_A" appears in the selection.
and I would like to know how I can do this in DAX in PowerBI. If anyone would be interested in providing some sample code I could try out, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want something like the COUNTX or COUNTAX function, combined with a FILTER, to replicate the functionality of Excel's COUNTIF.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countax-function-dax

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/countx-function-dax

Eg.

```
=COUNTAX(FILTER('YourTable',[BrandColumn]="Brand_A"),[BrandColumn])
```

Power BI's different "COUNT" functions have slightly different criteria in terms of whether a row gets counted or not (based on whether it's considering purely "empty" cells, or how the expression is evaluated), so you'd need to check the docs for each function and work out which one suits your specific requirement

(And by the way, a Google search of "Power BI COUNTIF" will give you plenty of results where you will find a range of different examples that should help)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this calculation (COUNTX may be slow, because its a iterator) :

```
CountIf = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS('YourTable' ), FILTER(ALL('YourTable'), 'YourTable'[Brand] = "YourBrand"))
```